# Should I prefix this method with Has or Have?

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style

This question might sound a little silly but I am curious which one is better. I have a method to check if we have enough disk space to continue our work. As in the previous sentence, I wrote "if we **have** enough ..." and I think I would name the method as `HaveEnoughDiskSpace`.

The problem is I rarely if never see a method begins with Have. I always see they begin with Has, for example, `HasPaid()`, `HasIssued()`, `HasChecked()`, and etc.

I am not sure if it's OK in this case to name it as `HaveEnoughDiskSpace` or it's better to name it as `HasEnoughDiskSpace`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about English grammar and style.

Comment: I think "HasEnoughDiskSpace" - disk **has** enough space.

Comment: `HasPaid`, `HasIssued` and `HasChecked` can also be written as `HavePaid`, `HaveIssued` and `HaveChecked`. So, a computer "Has" enough disk space, and you're meta-questioning.

Comment: @Aniket What is meta-questioning?

Comment: The computer asking itself a question after you giving it an instruction to ask question is metaquestioning. I just made it up.

Comment: Personal choice question... In most cases object represent a single entity "it", so "it has something" is more appropriate than "it have something". Note that for samples you've shown "it is XXXX" -`IsChecked`, or even `Checked` may be better.

Comment: It is similar to computers writing programs after you having given it instructions to write programs. i borrowed it from the word "metaprogramming"

Comment: The downvotes fairies are string with this question ...

Comment: @Noctis Yeah I don't understand why. The downvote button is labelled with "This answer is not useful." I think everybody who has answered has provided a useful answer, since - contrary to popular opinion, apparently - this question does in fact have a well-reasoned answer. You should use "Has," not "Have."

Comment: @TimothyShields , yep, but it's a rather silly question to begin with, not very code oriented, and it's more about style and preference ... you could have gone easily with things like: **EnoughDiskSpaceToContinue** or **DiskSpaceRequirementOK** as well.

Comment: @Noctis It's code-oriented enough to merit this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Its an off topic for the site but the answer is as following,

‘**Have**’ and ‘**has**’ are both used to denote possession, form the perfect tense, and the past tense of both is ‘had’, but they are used differently.

‘Have’ is used with

- the following pronouns: I, you, we, they. Examples : 'I have a pencil.' 'We have a big house.'
- pluralised nouns: Example : 'Doctors have a rough time, dealing with illnesses all the time.'

‘Has’ is used with the third person singular (he, she, it). Examples : 'She has your money.' 'Amit has the book.'

So in your case `HasPaid`, `HasIssued` and `HasChecked` makes more sense as you are refering to the 3rd party elements.

Comment: there is no need to downvote this answer,its an answer,downvote only if its wrong,its different that this question is out of context,you should downvote question,rather than the answer X-(

Answer (score 0):

Which sounds better?

```
X has enough disk space.
```

or

```
X have enough disk space.
```

Since the usage is going to be either `X.HasEnoughDiskSpace()` or `X.HaveEnoughDiskSpace()`, it would make sense to use the `Has` version.

Comment: That depends on what X is. If X is a collection of things, your answer is wrong. `PeopleHasOrders` is wrong.

Comment: @Asad This is an **instance** method. In the OP's scenario, an instance clearly does not represent a collection. It's a singular instance.

Comment: Why exactly can't an instance be a collection?

Comment: @Asad "In the OP's scenario, . . ."

Comment: Yes, I'm asking how you're concluding that in the OP's scenario, the class which will have this instance method is not a collection.

Comment: @Asad It's a fair assumption that "This computer" is the substitute for the blank in "_____ has enough disk space." Don't sue me if I'm wrong though. :)